# Find the best big-$O$ estimate for the equations below

Tags: limits, notation, algorithms, asymptotics

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to calculate the big-O. I haven't really found a credible source that could breakdown and explain how to approach such a question when asked.
I stumbled across a question that asks to calculate the big-O for these:

**A.** $(n - 1)(n + 2)$

**B.** $2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + ... + 2n$

**C.** $(n^3 + n^2 log\space n)(log\space n + 1) + (17log\space n + 19)(n^3 + 2)$

**D.** $(2^n + n^2)(n^3 + 3^n)$

**E.** $(n^n + n2^n + 5^n)(n! + 5^n)$

---

**For A:** After we expand, we get $n^2 + n - 2$. Taking the highest exponent, the big-O is $O(n^2)$

As for the other 4, I am completely clueless. Not even sure if $A$ is correct.

I just know that in order to calculate the big-O, I can use: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$ but I got no clue how to execute this on the equatiosn above.

Your feedback is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: You refer to **the** big-O, but it's never unique. Sure $n^2+n-2$ is $O(n^2)$, but it's also $O(73n^2)$ and $O(.73n^2)$ and $O(n^2+n+100000)$ and $O(n^3)$ and $O(10^n)$ and so on and so on. So, what do you really want?

Comment: Just determining the *best* big-O of each equation within A. B. C. D. E.
I came with: $A$ and $B = O(n^2)$, $C = O(n^3 log\space n)$, $D = O(6^n)$, and $E = O(n^n n!)$.... Which is correct and which isn't?

Comment: What is "better": $O(3 n^2 + \log n)$ or $O(n^2 + n)$? (I think you are actually interested in $\Theta$, not $O$)

Comment: We haven't covered anything other than $O$ during lectures. The general idea is just to find the Big-$O$ based off these basics here: https://prnt.sc/xt9HcRU1_VJY

Comment: One could argue that the "best" big-O for any function $f(n)$ is to say $f(n)$ is $O(f(n))$. Evidently, that's not what you want, so there's still a need for you to clarify.